# How to get a "cool" contour map in Matlab / Octave?

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

I have in mind this:

[image]

as opposed to this (note that I am not interested in the fact that the Gaussian plot above corresponds to uncorrelated normal variables):

```
pkg load 'statistics'
mu = [0,0]; %// data
sigma = [1 0.8; 0.8 1]; %// data
x = -3:.2:3; %// x axis
y = -3:.2:3; %// y axis

[X Y] = meshgrid(x,y); %// all combinations of x, y
Z = mvnpdf([X(:) Y(:)],mu,sigma); %// compute Gaussian pdf
Z = reshape(Z,size(X)); %// put into same size as X, Y
%// contour(X,Y,Z), axis equal  %// contour plot; set same scale for x and y...
surf(X,Y,Z) %// ... or 3D plot

fprintf("Program pause press enter to see the contour plot.")
pause

contour(X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

This latter plot would go with `mesh(X,Y,Z)`, which yields:

[image]

... leaving aside different likes and dislikes...

Thanks to a comment below, I am getting close to the original image with `countourf(X,Y,Z)`:

[image]

Comment: You do realize that the first ones are `mesh`/`surf` objects not contours, right?

Comment: @Suever No. I just started using Octave, and I'm completely unfamiliar with it. Is there a function for the plot I'm suggesting?

Comment: I just mentioned them: `mesh` and `surf`. Also it looks like you're already using `surf`, but you're overwriting it with the  `contour`.

Comment: @Suever Yes, the code is not mine. However when I replace the last line with `mesh(X, Y, Z)`, I get the bivariate pdf normal "bell" that goes with the last of the images in the OP -i.e. made up of iso-lines.

Comment: Things to check out: `help surf`, `help contourf`. If these don't help, you're question is even more unclear than expected.